# R dropping coefficient of one categorical column when there are two categorical columns (intercept removed)

Tags: r, regression, regression-coefficients, generalized-additive-model

I have two categorical columns in my dataset and I want to fit the GAM model on my data. I remove the intercept in the model by subtracting 1 from the model formula so that no category is used as the base category. However, this works only for one categorical column. In the resulting model, the intercept AND the reference value of the second categorical column, both are missing.

Look at the code and the output below, this will make things more clear.

```
df <- daily
df$time <- c(1:length(daily[[1]]))
df$month <- as.factor(month(df$date))
df$day <- as.factor(weekdays(daily$date))


# Fit the GAM model without a reference level and without an intercept
gam.fit = gam(df$domestic ~ s(df$time)+ df$month + df$day - 1)

# Print the summary of the GAM model
summary(gam.fit)
```

The output of this is as follows. Note that there is not intercept and there is no coefficient for the Friday category. How can I deal with this issue?

````
Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

Formula:
df$domestic ~ s(df$time) + df$month + df$day - 1 - 1

Parametric coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
df$month1       17951.49     212.97  84.293  < 2e-16 ***
df$month2       18203.96     221.15  82.313  < 2e-16 ***
df$month3       19750.00     197.33 100.087  < 2e-16 ***
df$month4       18150.32     197.59  91.857  < 2e-16 ***
df$month5       18792.48     192.45  97.648  < 2e-16 ***
df$month6       21817.08     194.42 112.215  < 2e-16 ***
df$month7       22082.12     192.37 114.792  < 2e-16 ***
df$month8       19816.95     191.13 103.685  < 2e-16 ***
df$month9       16514.15     194.98  84.695  < 2e-16 ***
df$month10      17822.43     192.96  92.363  < 2e-16 ***
df$month11      17494.93     196.23  89.154  < 2e-16 ***
df$month12      19855.97     198.34 100.110  < 2e-16 ***
df$dayMonday     -714.57     170.25  -4.197 2.88e-05 ***
df$daySaturday   1032.32     170.19   6.066 1.70e-09 ***
df$daySunday       20.59     170.22   0.121  0.90374    
df$dayThursday   -510.52     169.99  -3.003  0.00272 ** 
df$dayTuesday   -2069.01     170.25 -12.153  < 2e-16 ***
df$dayWednesday -1251.44     170.23  -7.351 3.35e-13 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
             edf Ref.df     F p-value    
s(df$time) 5.217  6.076 27.74  <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.566   Deviance explained = 99.2%
GCV = 2.9449e+06  Scale est. = 2.8961e+06  n = 1401
```
````

Comment: What "issue"?  This is appropriate behavior.

Comment: @PeterFlom, if you see the model summary, there is no intercept and no coefficient for Friday category. Shouldn't Friday also have the coefficient?

Comment: This is a general behavior, not specific to my dataset. I tried generating a random toy dataset with two categorical columns. If I want to interpret the relationship of response variable with each category in each categorical columns, it is not possible right now.

Comment: You can change the contrast coding for categorical variables. See https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/library/r-library-contrast-coding-systems-for-categorical-variables/  .  I've never done this for GAM, but I don't see why it would not work. E.g. Deviation coding will give every level of the categorical variables a parameter estimate.  But be careful to interpret things correctly

Comment: The answer from eev2 summarizes the situation well. In my experience it's usually better to keep the intercepts in the original model and then get predictions for each of the levels of categorical variables with post-modeling tools like those in the [`emmeans` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=emmeans), which [supports GAM models](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/models.html) produced by the `mgcv`, `gam`, or `gamlss` packages.

Answer (score 1):

Technically speaking, it has to drop one level from the second variable, otherwise the design matrix won't be full rank. To see this, suppose that indicator variables are included in the design matrix for all levels of the second variable as well. Then summing all the columns corresponding to the first variable will give all 1's. Summing all the columns corresponding to the second variable, will also give all 1's. So, substracting the second variable's columns from the first variable's columns you get all 0's, therefore the matrix is not full rank.

Intuitively, say dayFriday was also estimated. Each data point corresponds to a month and a day, so the estimated average for a given month and a given day will be the sum of the corresponding parameters. You can add a fixed value to all the month parameters, and subtract the same fixed value from all the day parameters, and the estimated average of month + day won't change. So there is no unique way of determining all parameters if all months and all days are included.